# Jquery POST call with XML payload

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, post

I have to a service which expects following input message for successful invocation. I invoked the service using curl.

```
POST /airavata-registry-rest-services/registry/api/hostdescriptor/save HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
Host: 127.0.0.1
Accept: text/plain
Content-Type: text/xml
Content-Length: 191

<type:hostDescription xmlns:type="http://schemas.airavata.apache.org/gfac/type">
   <type:hostName>LocalHost11</type:hostName>
   <type:hostAddress>127.0.0.1</type:hostAddress></type:hostDescription>
```

The curl command I used was;

```
curl -H "Accept: text/plain" -X POST -H "Content-Type: text/xml" -d '<type:hostDescription xmlns:type="http://schemas.airavata.apache.org/gfac/type"><type:hostName>LocalHost11</type:hostName><type:hostAddress>127.0.0.1</type:hostAddress></type:hostDescription>' http://localhost:6060/airavata-registry-rest-services/registry/api/hostdescriptor/save
```

I'm trying to invoke the same service through Jquery and I am not able to generate the same request. The code I have written is;

```
    var hostName = $("#hostName1").val();
    var hostAddress = $("#hostAddress1").val();
    var xml = $('<type:hostDescription xmlns:type="http://schemas.airavata.apache.org/gfac/type"><type:hostName>' + hostName + '</type:hostName><type:hostAddress>' + hostAddress + '</type:hostAddress></type:hostDescription>');

    var xmlData= $(xml);
    var xmlString;
    if (window.ActiveXObject){
        xmlString = xmlData.xml;
    } else {
        var oSerializer = new XMLSerializer();
        xmlString = oSerializer.serializeToString(xmlData[0]);
    }
    console.log(xmlString);

    $.ajax({
        headers: {
            Accept : "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
            "Content-Type": "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
            "Accept-Encoding" : ""
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "http://localhost:6060/airavata-registry-rest-services/registry/api/hostdescriptor/save",
        data: xmlString,
        dataType: "xml",
        cache: false,
        error: function() { alert("No data found."); },
        success: function(xml) {
            alert("it works");
        }
    }).done(function( msg ) {
                alert( "Data Saved: " + msg );
            });
```

The request the above method generates is like below. It's missing the message body as well. Can you suggest how I can change my jquery function to call the above mentioned service.

```
OPTIONS /airavata-registry-rest-services/registry/api/hostdescriptor/save HTTP/1.1
Host: 127.0.0.1
Connection: keep-alive
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Origin: http://localhost:7080
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/536.11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu/12.04 Chromium/20.0.1132.47 Chrome/20.0.1132.47 Safari/536.11
Access-Control-Request-Headers: origin, contenttype, content-type, accept
Accept: */*
Referer: http://localhost:7080/client-api-demo/x_host_descriptor_save.html
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3
```

Comment: Aren't you missing the parameter name in the data, how was your curl request, exactly?

Comment: @felipeclopes I edited my question to have the curl command.

Answer (score 0):

I just notice a difference in the Content-Type passed in your curl request from your AJAX request.

The curl request use the following Content-Type:

```
"Content-Type: text/xml"
```

In the headers you may set this way:

```
headers: {
            Accept : "text/plain; charset=utf-8",
            "Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"
        },
```

Also I believe you are not including the parameter name when passing the data. Your data may be set with the parameter it belongs to, depending on the name that you are expecting in your service:

```
data: { inputxml: escape(xmlString)}
```

Hope this helps!